# How can I make an SVG pattern vary its repetition count as container dimension varies?

Tags: svg

I have got this test image that shows two rectangles filled with 16 circles each:

```html
<svg width="500" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="Gradient1">
      <stop offset="5%" stop-color="white"/>
      <stop offset="95%" stop-color="blue"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <pattern id="Pattern" x="0" y="0" width=".25" height=".25">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" fill="skyblue"/>
      <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="url(#Gradient1)" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect fill="url(#Pattern)" stroke="red" width="200" height="200"/>
  <rect fill="url(#Pattern)" stroke="red" width="200" height="400" x="210"/>
</svg>
```

I would like the same pattern to neatly fill the two rectangles, without gaps between circles and without stretching of the circles.  The rectangle at right has room for 32 circles, and I want to see them all in there, but instead there are 16 with gaps.

Is there any way to change the single pattern here so that it'll neatly fill one rectangle with 16 tiles and the other with 32?  It seems like a very basic thing to want to do, but I've fussed with the many coordinate- and transformation-related parameters of the pattern for a while and found no way.

In this simple example it's easy enough to work around the problem by, say, making two patterns for the two rectangles instead of having them share one, and tweaking `height` for the tall rectangle's pattern.  But in the real project where I want to use patterns, bounding boxes on pattern-filled shapes have unpredictable dimensions, and so I can't easily alter the tile dimensions to compensate for their variation...  as far as I can tell, anyway.

Am I missing something?  Or is the pattern system just not designed for this usage, simple and basic though it may seem?  Maybe I should be using clip paths or masks or something to cut my tilings out of a big, easily controlled square instead of applying a pattern to each shape I want to tile??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `patternUnits ="userSpaceOnUse"` and replace the dimensions of the pattern parameters with absolute values.

For example: instead of `width =".25"` set `width ="50px"`

```html
<svg width="500" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="Gradient1">
      <stop offset="5%" stop-color="white"/>
      <stop offset="95%" stop-color="blue"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <pattern id="Pattern" x="0" y="0" width="50px" height="50px" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" fill="skyblue"/>
      <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="url(#Gradient1)" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect fill="url(#Pattern)" stroke="red" width="200" height="200"/>
  <rect fill="url(#Pattern)" stroke="red" width="200" height="400" x="250"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: When I try this, I seem to see no difference whether the absolute units are used or not.  But the patternUnits attribute makes all the difference.  It turns out that my original problem was that although I tried patternContentUnits, I never noticed that patternUnits existed as well.  I thought there was only one of those attributes, not two!

Comment: @mjwach  Тhаnk you.  You can see that it matters which units we choose absolute or relative. If the size of one tile of the pattern is set to 50 x 50 px, then the pattern accurately fills the rectangles with sizes multiple of 50 (100, 200, 300, 400)